# MQ window to Unix special chars

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using .net client to post mesages to MQ server which is hosted on Unix. It is added some control character before the messages. Like below

```
**^CD**<request>
```

The Queue connection is through SSL Table channel connection. 
The code i am using is

```
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager ; 
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_BIND_NOT_FIXED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING; 
MQQueue Queue = queueManager.AccessQueue("TestQueue", openOptions); 
MQMessage queueMessage = new MQMessage(); 
queueMessage.WriteUTF("<request>"); 

MQPutMessageOptions MessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions(); 
Queue.Put(queueMessage, MessageOptions);
```

please let me know what cause this special chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From IBM's own [doco](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqtan.doc/amqtan0337.htm) on `WriteUTF`:

> This method takes an ActiveX string and writes it into the message data buffer at the current position in UTF format. The data written **consists of a 2-byte length followed by the character data**. DataOffset is incremented by the length of the string if the method succeeds.

If you don't want that length, consider using `WriteString` instead (follow that doco link above and just go up a couple of lines in the navigation pane)..

Comment: Man, I'm off my game tonight.  This is of course, the correct answer.  :-)  The link to the same doc in the v7 manual is http://bit.ly/a7YvFW  I hope everyone is using the v7 classes, client an dserver by now, right?  The v6 version is end-of-life as of Sep 2011 and for .Net the v7 classes are SO much better it's worth it to switch now.

Comment: Is there any possibility writestring strip of Len of string?

Comment: @user171523, not sure I understand. WriteString won't actually write the length like WriteUTF does so, in that sense, yes it does strip it off. Of course, if it's a variable length string and you're going to put more data after it, you should have the length in there.